# Font Awesome Icon aligns wrong in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-awesome-4

Applied the FontAwesome icon "caret-right" to three li-/a-tags in my menu, to indicate the presence of submenus. The icons shall be right-aligned. My code works in Chrome and Edge, but doesn't in Firefox. Read about a possible problem with loading the FA files via CDN, so I switched to loading them from my webspace, with no success. I can see the icons at the end of the menu items, but they are cut off and pushed down.
Here's my HTML and CSS:

```html
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="de">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../css/reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../css/960.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <title>Titel</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body, select, input, textarea, button {
     font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
     font-size: 13px;
     line-height: 1.5em;
        }
    nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }
    nav > ul > li {
        float: left;
        }
    nav > ul > li > ul {
        display: none;
        }
    nav > ul a {
        display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #444;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        }
    nav > ul > li > a:after {
     content: "\f0d7";
     font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        padding-left: 0.35em
        }
    nav > ul li > a:only-child:after {
        content: "";
        }
    nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        }
    nav > ul > li > ul > li {
        position: relative;
        }
    nav > ul > li > ul > li > a:after {
     float: right;
        content: "\f0da";
     font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        padding-left: 1em
        }
    nav > ul li > a:only-child:after {
        content: "";
        }
    nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
        display: none;
        }
    nav > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
        }
    </style>
      </head>
      <body>
       <nav>
      <ul class="grid_12">
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="./mitglieder/mitglieder.php">Mitglieder</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Clubturniere</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="./cm/cm.php">Clubmeisterschaft</a></li>
         <li><a href="./mobl/mobl_gw.php">Monats-Blitzturniere</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="./mannschaft/mannschaften.php">Mannschaften</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Bayerische Meisterschaft</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/m1.php">1. Mannschaft</a></li>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/m2.php">2. Mannschaft</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Münchner Meisterschaft</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/m3.php">3. Mannschaft</a></li>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/m4.php">4. Mannschaft</a></li>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/m5.php">5. Mannschaft</a></li>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/m6.php">6. Mannschaft</a></li>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/m7.php">7. Mannschaft</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Senioren</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/sen_m1.php">Senioren 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/sen_m2.php">Senioren 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="./termine/termine.php">Termine</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Schachaufgaben</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="./aufgaben/schachaufgaben_1.php">Nummer 1&#8201;&#8211;&#8201;18</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./aufgaben/schachaufgaben_2.php">Nummer 19&#8201;&#8211;&#8201;36</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
       <li><a href="./archiv/archiv.php">Archiv</a></li>
       <li><a href="./kontakt/kontakt.php">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The link to the file is http://msc1836.bplaced.net/menutest.html
OS is Win-10, Firefox version is 50.1.0.

Can anybody help?
Thx, Mike

Comment: remove `white-space: nowrap;` from  `nav > ul a`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `white-space` form `nav > ul a` and it's working properly

```html
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="de">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../css/reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../css/960.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <title>Titel</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body, select, input, textarea, button {
     font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
     font-size: 13px;
     line-height: 1.5em;
        }
    nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }
    nav > ul > li {
        float: left;
        }
    nav > ul > li > ul {
        display: none;
        }
    nav > ul a {
        display: block;
        //white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #444;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        }
    nav > ul > li > a:after {
     content: "\f0d7";
     font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        padding-left: 0.35em
        }
    nav > ul li > a:only-child:after {
        content: "";
        }
    nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        }
    nav > ul > li > ul > li {
        position: relative;
        }
    nav > ul > li > ul > li > a:after {
     float: right;
        content: "\f0da";
     font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        padding-left: 1em
        }
    nav > ul li > a:only-child:after {
        content: "";
        }
    nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
        display: none;
        }
    nav > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
        }
    </style>
      </head>
      <body>
       <nav>
      <ul class="grid_12">
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="./mitglieder/mitglieder.php">Mitglieder</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Clubturniere</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="./cm/cm.php">Clubmeisterschaft</a></li>
         <li><a href="./mobl/mobl_gw.php">Monats-Blitzturniere</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="./mannschaft/mannschaften.php">Mannschaften</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Bayerische Meisterschaft</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/m1.php">1. Mannschaft</a></li>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/m2.php">2. Mannschaft</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Münchner Meisterschaft</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/m3.php">3. Mannschaft</a></li>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/m4.php">4. Mannschaft</a></li>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/m5.php">5. Mannschaft</a></li>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/m6.php">6. Mannschaft</a></li>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/m7.php">7. Mannschaft</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Senioren</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/sen_m1.php">Senioren 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="./mannschaft/sen_m2.php">Senioren 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="./termine/termine.php">Termine</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Schachaufgaben</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="./aufgaben/schachaufgaben_1.php">Nummer 1&#8201;&#8211;&#8201;18</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./aufgaben/schachaufgaben_2.php">Nummer 19&#8201;&#8211;&#8201;36</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
       <li><a href="./archiv/archiv.php">Archiv</a></li>
       <li><a href="./kontakt/kontakt.php">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `white-space` in the `nav > ul a` which is affecting the `float: right` pseudo elements in Firefox.

However to keep your `li` elements in a straight line, give a `min-width` value as such:

```
nav > ul a {
    display: block;
    min-width: 90px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Minal Chauhan and nashcheez for your quick response. Removing the `white-space` command from the `nav > ul a` section solved the problem. I additionally applied a `min-width` to my 3rd level links, whose lines would have been wrapped otherwise.